# Notification when a user comes online in Discord

Tags: notifications, discord

I am using Discord and I would like to get a notification sound when my friend Mike comes online. I would like to get a notification only when he comes online, and not for other friends. If that option does not exist then at least a notification when any friend comes online.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this feature doesn't exist. There's no way for you to get a notification when a friend comes online.

A canonical request for this feature is available on the [Discord support page](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360029483771). It's very highly upvoted by thousands of users, so there's some hope that it will be implemented.

For now, though, this isn't possible.